# About parentheses bug in sympy.printing.mathml

Tags: python, sympy, mathjax, mathml

I converted a Python string into a formula with sympify as follows:

I converted the formula into MathML format with the mathml command.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml

print(mathml(sympify("(2*x + 3*y + 1)*(4*x**2 - 6*x*y - 2*x + 9*y**2 - 3*y + 1)"),printer='presentation'))
```

As a result, the following code was output.

```
<mrow><mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mrow><mrow><mn>4</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>6</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mrow><mn>9</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><msup><mi>y</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow></mrow>
```

I embedded the code in HTML and tried it as follows.

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script async="" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
</head>
<body>
<math>
<mrow><mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mrow><mrow><mn>4</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>6</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>2</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mrow><mn>9</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><msup><mi>y</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></mrow><mo>-</mo><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo><mi>y</mi></mrow><mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow></mrow>
</math>
</body>
</html>
```

However, with this code, the output will be missing the Parentheses, as in the image below.

[![画像の説明をここに入力][1]][1]

I read the [source code of sympy.printing.mathml][2].

So I wondered what the `_print_Interval` method is used for.

Is this related to the problem of missing Parentheses in formulas?

This expression is an example. 
I want to convert even more complicated formulas properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in the Japanese version of stackoverflow.
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/55578/22541

Fixing [this][1] can solve the problem.

[Before]

```
for term in terms:
    x = self._print(term)
    mrow.appendChild(x)
```

[After]

```
for term in terms:
    mrow.appendChild(self.parenthesize(term, PRECEDENCE['Mul']))
```

Answer (score 0):

In an `isympy` session:

```
In [56]: sympify("(2*x + 3*y + 1)*(4*x**2 - 6*x*y - 2*x + 9*y**2 - 3*y + 1)")                          
Out[56]: 
                ⎛   2                    2          ⎞
(2⋅x + 3⋅y + 1)⋅⎝4⋅x  - 6⋅x⋅y - 2⋅x + 9⋅y  - 3⋅y + 1⎠
```

Comment: What does this mean?　I printed only sympify but it didn't go wrong.　In:`print(sympify("(2*x + 3*y + 1)*(4*x**2 - 6*x*y - 2*x + 9*y**2 - 3*y + 1)"))`　Out: `(2*x + 3*y + 1)*(4*x**2 - 6*x*y - 2*x + 9*y**2 - 3*y + 1)`

Comment: The correct grouping is present the `mathml` expression.  `print_mathml` does a pretty print.  So the fault is the html rendering.

Comment: @hpaulj, The MathML is at fault, not the html rendering.  The MathML given above is presentation MathML, and that requires that all markup be present, including parentheses.  An `mrow` does not imply parentheses if they are not present in the markup.  The proper MathML would begin with `<math><mrow><mo>(</mo><mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn>...` (you could also do this with `mfenced` elements, as the Japanese answer does).  If the `mathml()` function returned *content* MathML, then you would get implied parentheses.  That's just not the case with presentation MathML, however.